# how to show the data in a texbox in table?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a "Add" button on clicking the button it will add two textbox with popup calendar and a radio button. What I need is after the fills the text box and clicks submit button it should display the filled data above the text box in the form of table with columns **start date** and **enddate** along with delete option to remove the date from the column. Can anyone provide an example if possible.
Thanks in advance
Edit:whichever the radio is selected only that row should be kept in table

The below code add the div and popup calendar

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".datepicker").each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });

    $("#btnAddAddress").click(function () {

        $(".container").show();
        $(".container").append('<table> <tr> <td> <label ID="lblStartDate">Start   Date </label> </td> <td> <input type="text"  class="datepicker"/><label id="lblEndDate" >End Date</label></td><td><input type="text" class="datepicker"/> </td> <td><input type="radio" /></td></tr></table>');
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();

    });

});
```

ADD button

```html
<div class="AAA">
    <input type="button" id="btnAddAddress" name="btnAddAddress" value="Add" />
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

Submit button

```html
<div class="submit">
    <input type="button" value="submit" />
</div>
```

please look here:http://jsfiddle.net/saranyasaint/ksjn7ko7/

Comment: so whichever the radio is selected only that row should be kept in table? or howmuch ever row is added all the row values?

Comment: yes ..whichever the radio is selected only that row should be kept in table@GuruprasadRao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ksjn7ko7/11/)**

```
$('.btnsubmit').on('click',function(){
   if($('table').length)
   {
        var radio=$('input[type="radio"]:checked');
        var stDate=$(radio).closest('table').find('.datepicker:first').val();
        var edDate=$(radio).closest('table').find('.datepicker:last').val();
        var html="<tr><td> "+stDate+"</td><td>"+edDate+"</td><td><a href='#' class='rmv'>Remove</a>";
        //$('.tbl').append(html);//Use append if you want to append data to table
        $('.tbl').html(html);//Replace exisiting content and add new one
    }
    else
        alert('add data please');  
})

$(document).on('click','.rmv',function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ksjn7ko7/15/)**

```
$('.btnsubmit').on('click',function(){
        if($('table').length)
        {
            var radio=$('input[type="radio"]:checked');
            var stDate=$(radio).closest('table').find('.datepicker:first').val();
            var edDate=$(radio).closest('table').find('.datepicker:last').val();
            var car=$("#yourselectid option:selected").text()
            var html="<tr><td> "+stDate+"</td><td>"+edDate+"</td><td>"+car+"</td><td><a href='#' class='rmv'>Remove</a>";
            //$('.tbl').append(html);//Use append to append to table
            $('.tbl').html(html);//Replace exisiting content and add new one
        }
        else
            alert('add data please');  
})
```

> **Note - I've skipped some validations which you might need to do**

Comment: ..how do i get the data from a drop down list ex:let say "a" and "b" .if i select "a" along with dates in a table@guruprasad rao

Comment: quite confusing! can you elaborate more? with a demo if possible?

Comment: I have a dropdown list with values let say "benz" and "volvo".if i select benz on clicking submit it should show it in the table along with dates..hope i am clear now..@guruprasad rao

Comment: @sheelabalaji updated answer.. check and let me know!!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

This fiddle works, see here http://jsfiddle.net/ksjn7ko7/14/ or try out the following code snippet.

New dates are added with "add" button, "submit" button then turns input fields into plain text and makes "delete" button visible. "delete" button will delete all rows not being checked. The radio-input fields all need to have the same name if you want the "radio-function" to work, i. e. only one of them can be checked. Otherwise you should use a checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#sbmt').click(function(){
   $('#btnAddAddress,#sbmt').hide();$('#dlt').show();
   $('.container input[type=text]')
       .each(function(){$(this).replaceWith($(this).val());}); 
  });
  $('#dlt').click(function(){
   $('.container tr').has('input:not(:checked)').remove();
  })
  $("#btnAddAddress").click(function () {
    $(".container,#sbmt").show();
    $(".container").append('<table> <tr> <td> <label ID="lblStartDate">Start Date </label> </td> <td> <input type="text"  class="datepicker"/><label id="lblEndDate" >End Date</label></td><td><input type="text" class="datepicker"/> </td> <td><input type="radio" name="rdb"/></td></tr></table>');
        
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
  });
});
```

```css
#dlt,#sbmt {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="AAA">
<input type="button" id="btnAddAddress" name="btnAddAddress" value="Add"  /> 
<input type="button" value="submit" id="sbmt"/>
<input type="button" value="delete unchecked dates" id="dlt"/>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```